# How to make sidebar with 100% height that overlays header but in same time doesnt overlay footer

Tags: html, css, drupal, layout, drupal-theming

I am editing Drupal theme and I am trying to figure out how to make sidebar that would stretch according to content, overlay header but in same time wont overlay footer. Kinda hard to explain, so I draw an image -> http://i48.tinypic.com/hs2r9t.png

I already made green area - content flexible, so when I add articles to it, it will stretch and move footer deeper.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Never used Drupal, but in HTML+CSS the following would work for you:

```
#sidebar { 
    float: left; /* push it to the left */
}
#header { 
    overflow: hidden; /* new block formatting context */
}
#content { 
    overflow: hidden; 
}
#footer { 
    clear: left; /* clear the float */
}​
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ju2S3/)

If you're planning on working with layout, it is a must that you learn HTML and CSS.